# Liveness and readiness probe connection refused

Tags: http, kubernetes, ansible-awx, readinessprobe, livenessprobe

I keep getting this error when I try to setup liveness & readiness prob for my awx_web container

```
Liveness probe failed: Get http://POD_IP:8052/: dial tcp POD_IP:8052: connect: connection refused
```

Liveness & Readiness section in my deployment for the container awx_web

```
          ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 8052 # the port of the container awx_web
            protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 8052
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 5
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 8052
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 5
```

if I test if the port 8052 is open or not from another pod in the same namespace as the pod that contains the container awx_web or if I test using a container deployed in the same pod as the container awx_web i get this (port is open)

```
/ # nc -vz POD_IP 8052
POD_IP  (POD_IP :8052) open
```

I get the same result (port 8052 is open) if I use netcat (nc) from the worker node where pod containing the container awx_web is deployed.

for info I use a NodePort service that redirect traffic to that container (awx_web)

```
type: NodePort
ports:
- name: http
  port: 80
  targetPort: 8052
  nodePort: 30100
```

Comment: If you do `curl http://POD_IP:8052/` from another pod..does it work?

Comment: From another pod, container in the same pod or from the worker node, yes it works

Comment: check kubelet and cni plugin pod logs

Comment: for kubelet log, it gave the same error

Answer (score 14):

In my case this issue has occurred because I've configured the backend application host as `localhost`. The issue is resolved when I changed the host value to `0.0.0.0` inside my app properties.

Use the latest built docker image after making this change.

Comment: That was exactly my problem also. Changing to `0.0.0.0` fixed the problem

Answer (score 13):

I recreated your issue and it looks like your problem is caused by too small value of `initialDelaySeconds` for the liveness probe.

It takes more than 5s for awx container to open 8052 port.
You need to wait a bit longer for it to start. I have found out that setting it to 15s is enough for me, but you may require some tweaking.

Comment: i already incremented initialDelaySeconds to 30s then to 60s but still the same issue

Comment: With liveness probe being set, could you exec to pod as soon as it starts and run `watch -n1 "ss -lnt"` and check when port 8052 opens?

Comment: the container has `State: Running` and `Ready: False`, when i issue your command the port 8052 is missing from the list

Comment: Is it always missing or maybe it appears after some time? Also please check logs `kubectl logs -n <namespace> <pod_name>`, maybe there are some errors.@Adamsin

Comment: Do you have any other ports open? In my case that is 8050 and also 8051. And what version of awx are you using (I was testing on 14.1.0)?

Comment: regarding pod logs there is nothing noticeable, for AWX i use 9.3.0 version and for the ports you mentioned i see them when there is no probes but i don't see them if the probes are in place

Comment: I deployed awx 9.3.0 and it looks like it takes awx-web container whole 5min before it opens port 8052 and starts serving traffic. This is why liveness probe is failing. Check it yourself; remove the probes, exec to the container, `watch ss -lnt`, and measure the time since the pods start to port 8052 is open.

Comment: your are right, exactly as you said but i don't understand why it takes so much time for the container to start listening on the designated port when i use probes while it takes only few seconds 10-20s without probes ?!

Comment: I can't help you with this. You can create an issue on [awx github repo](https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues) asking this question to developers directly, but I am not sure version 9.x.x is still supported so you may not get the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely your application couldnt startup or crash little after it start up . It may due to insufficient memory and cpu resource. Or one of the awx dependency not setup correctly like postgreslq & rabbit.

Did you check that if your application works correctly without probes? I recommend do that first. Examine the pods stats little bit to ensure its not restart.

Comment: i did run awx without probes and it functions perfectly